# How can I track the window's user activities?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, authentication, logoff

I need to track the users activities similar to Audit policy. 
If possible I'd like to track a windows user's activities using my own program. Thanks in advance...
I am using following code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using COMAdmin;
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static SensEvents SensEvents = new SensEvents();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SensEvents.LogonEvent += OnSensLogonEvent;
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for events. Press [ENTER] to stop.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void OnSensLogonEvent(object sender, SensLogonEventArgs e)
        {
            String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            Console.WriteLine("Type:" + e.Type + ", UserName:" + e.UserName + ", SessionId:" + e.SessionId + ", Date :" + date);
        }
    }

    public sealed class SensEvents
    {
        private static readonly Guid SENSGUID_EVENTCLASS_LOGON2 = new Guid("d5978650-5b9f-11d1-8dd2-00aa004abd5e");
        private Sink _sink;

        public event EventHandler<SensLogonEventArgs> LogonEvent;

        public SensEvents()
        {
            _sink = new Sink(this);
            COMAdminCatalogClass catalog = new COMAdminCatalogClass(); 

            ICatalogCollection subscriptions = (ICatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("TransientSubscriptions");

            ICatalogObject subscription = (ICatalogObject)subscriptions.Add();
            subscription.set_Value("EventCLSID", SENSGUID_EVENTCLASS_LOGON2.ToString("B"));
            subscription.set_Value("SubscriberInterface", _sink);
            // NOTE: we don't specify a method name, so all methods may be called
            subscriptions.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void OnLogonEvent(SensLogonEventType type, string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId)
        {
            EventHandler<SensLogonEventArgs> handler = LogonEvent;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new SensLogonEventArgs(type, bstrUserName, dwSessionId));
            }
        }

        private class Sink : ISensLogon2
        {
            private SensEvents _events;

            public Sink(SensEvents events)
            {
                _events = events;
            }

            public void Logon(string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId)
            {
                _events.OnLogonEvent(SensLogonEventType.Logon, bstrUserName, dwSessionId);
            }

            public void Logoff(string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId)
            {
                _events.OnLogonEvent(SensLogonEventType.Logoff, bstrUserName, dwSessionId);
            }

            public void SessionDisconnect(string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId)
            {
                _events.OnLogonEvent(SensLogonEventType.SessionDisconnect, bstrUserName, dwSessionId);
            }

            public void SessionReconnect(string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId)
            {
                _events.OnLogonEvent(SensLogonEventType.SessionReconnect, bstrUserName, dwSessionId);
            }

            public void PostShell(string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId)
            {
                _events.OnLogonEvent(SensLogonEventType.PostShell, bstrUserName, dwSessionId);
            }
        }

        [ComImport, Guid("D597BAB4-5B9F-11D1-8DD2-00AA004ABD5E")]
        private interface ISensLogon2
        {
            void Logon([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId);
            void Logoff([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId);
            void SessionDisconnect([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId);
            void SessionReconnect([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId);
            void PostShell([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUserName, uint dwSessionId);
        }
    }

    public class SensLogonEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public SensLogonEventArgs(SensLogonEventType type, string userName, uint sessionId)
        {
            Type = type;
            UserName = userName;
            SessionId = sessionId;
        }
        private String userName;
        public string UserName {
            get { return userName; }
            set { userName = value; }
           }
        private uint sessionId;
        public  uint SessionId {

            get { return sessionId; }
            set { sessionId = value; }
        }
        private SensLogonEventType type;
        public  SensLogonEventType Type {
            get { return type; }
            set { type = value; }
            //get; private set; 
        }
    }

    public enum SensLogonEventType
    {
        Logon,
        Logoff,
        SessionDisconnect,
        SessionReconnect,
        PostShell
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know I, potentially, removed your tribute to whoever. They're not needed. Thank users with upvotes and acceptances.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn on the built-in Auditing capabilities and read the audit log. It'll be a whole lot easier than trying to duplicate the same capabilities.

Comment: thanks responding if turn on built-in Auditing capabilities tracking down too much events may cause a considerable system slowdown. Even more, since not all user activity is of interest for logging, Auditing policies enable us capturing only event types that we consider being important.

Comment: You can audit only specific events, or access to specific resources.